# Firebase - Get all records which contains a key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a series of records in Firebase, like these:

```
{
  records: {
    n1: {
      f1: 1,
      f2: 0,
      f3: 1
    },
    n2: {
      f1: 0,
      f4: 1,
      f5: 0
    }
  }
}
```

I want, using an index, to get al records that contains the key `f1` whatever its content might be (0 or 1)

There's a way to do this with Firebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Queries cannot test for the existence of a property, only for their value.

The easiest way to work around this limitation is to add a property with a value that signals the existence of the property you're looking for. Yeah... that is probably easier to understand with an example:

```
{
    "records": {
        "n1": {
            "f1": 1,
            "f2": 0,
            "f3": 1,
            "has_f1": true
        },
        "n2": {
            "f1": 0,
            "f4": 1,
            "f5": 0,
            "has_f1": true
        },
        "n3": {
            "f7": 8,
            "f8": 0
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can query:

```
ref.child('records')
   .orderByChild('has_f1')
   .equalTo(true)
   .on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
       console.log(snapshot.val()); 
   })
```

Comment: Couldn't this be done without the extra field by using `ref.child('records').orderByChild('f1').startAt(0)`?

Comment: Yup. It didn't occur to me to do it that way, but indeed you can start at the minimum value for the type you store in there. Might be worth adding that as an alternative answer.

Comment: I'd rather just see it added to one authoritative answer as another option.