# How do I access an unknown node in firebase while retrieving data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the data beneath a node in Firebase which has an unknown ID. I have used **push().getKey()**, which assigns an unknown ID to each entry.

The structure of database is somewhat like this:
**Known ID**->{*Unknown ID 1*: data1, *Unknown ID 2*: data2, *Unknown ID 3*: data3}

What do I use to access the data, in such way:
`ref.child(Known ID).child(Unknown ID)--> data`
but keeping in mind the random Unknown ID?

Referred other answers, but couldn't conclude. Tried, but retrieved a Null.

Comment: Share the code where you are fetching the data and also where you are storing the unknown ID

Comment: @YashKrishanVerma, I am storing data inside the node identified by User ID (.getUid()) which is known. But inside this known node, user adds many records again and again which are identified by Unknown ID (Since unique ids cant repeat). I am not storing any Unknown ID, I want an idea on behalf of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TLDR:** If you don't know the ID/name of the child node, you can't fetch
>   it directly.

Now, as far as I can understand from your explanation, your structure is something like this:

Root>User>More data added with unknown IDs.

I suggest you restructure it like this.

Root>User>Another child node with name say "userData">Add more data here with the unique IDs

```
userID1234:{
    ....,
    records:{
        record1:{},
        record2:{},
        so on
    }
}
```

This will help you fetch you data in one go by adding listener on the userData child.

Now do this to fetch all the records:

```
//Single event listener
databaseReference.child(userID).child("records").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get all records
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                // Use the fetched data which contains all the records
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Root>User  1>[Record1{Rs. 1000, 5th Aug}, Record2{Rs. 500, 7th Aug}, Record3{Rs. 200, 9th Aug}... so on]. These records go on appending as user performs transactions. But I can't keep a log of record of each transaction. This is precisely the problem.

Comment: So basically, there would be a separate database for each Transaction ID vs User ID. Wouldn't it make the app slower, considering already the load of other database retrievals....?

Comment: Not separate DB but a new child node. And that is inevitable simply because you can't retrieve data without knowing it's address.

Comment: Alright! Thank you for your time! I'll surely try it out.

Comment: Thank you, the answer partly helped. I figured out an idea using the .orderByChild("key") method suggested on this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320379/firebase-get-all-records-which-contains-a-key

Comment: Well yes that definitely is a way. But you stated that you are not storing unknownID so I thought that method won't help. Anyway, all the best.

Comment: My bad, was unclear. I'll not be storing any unknown id. Ill try to figure it out using 1 unique id assigned to the user. Hope Im going the correct way..

Comment: Yes you headed in the right direction. My rule thumb has always been to store data in Firebase without worrying much about speed because it is very fast on the retrieval part. But you have to take care of things on the user side. I hope ordering it will help you. Also, try to rethink the structure if nothing helps